# Count in execquery for wql query

Tags: vb.net, wmi, wql

I am trying to connect to lenel and using WQL to fetch result. WQL when runned in WMI explorer returns record.

```
Set objServices = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/onguard")
Set cardSet = objServices.ExecQuery("select * from Lnl_Badge where id =11111")
if not cardSet is nothing then
Response.Write("<br/>cardset has something")
vContinue = true
else
Response.Write("<br/>cardSet set is nothing")
Exit Function
end if

Response.Write("<br/>count ")
Count = cardSet.Count
Response.Write(Count)
```

The problem is that the value of Count is coming nothing and program exit from the current function. Any idea what is wrong.

"Cardset has something" is displayed though.

Edit:

For checking the syntax i did the following for cim2v

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process")
Response.Write(colItems.Count)
for each colItem in colItems

If Not colItem Is Nothing Then
    Response.Write("<br/>")
Response.Write(colItem.ProcessID)
end if
next
```

To my suprise its working....then why the above code is not woking... :(

Edit:
error in the log file

```
(Tue Aug 20 11:50:22 2013.179589208) : WDM call returned error: 4200
(Tue Aug 20 11:50:22 2013.179589208) : WDM specific return code: 4200
(Tue Aug 20 11:50:22 2013.179589208) :
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of the WMI API reference, the [SWbemServices.ExecQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method will always return an SWbemObjectSet object if you didn't encounter an error, regardless of whether or not there are any results in that object.

If your query returns 0 results you'll still have a valid object in `cardSet`, so the `If Not cardSet Is Nothing` statement will always trigger, unless there was an error, but at the same time count will still return 0.